# Employer wants to know who isn't contributing to charity

Tags: employer, charity, human-resources

My employer is asking every employee to donate to a specific charity via an online form. This seems reasonable. However, they are also requesting that those who don't contribute will still fill in the online form expressly indicating that they are not willing to contribute. They are really pushing this.

Is anything fishy with that?

Edit with additional info:

- This is a US company
- The online form link is emailed to employees, and also on the employee home page.
- The online form is hosted by the *charity itself*, and not the company
- The word "required" isn't used; phrasing is "please donate..."
- I haven't asked HR about this

Comment: In what country? Is the online form something the employer controls? How is the employer linked to the form? Have you asked HR what the reason for requiring this form is? Depending on where you are from, your charitable contributions might be protected personal information...

Comment: As someone who gives to charities of my own choice, I hate it when my employer wants to divert some of my funds to their own charity.  I think this is fishy and a form of coercion, but maybe not illegal depending on where you are.  If I wasn't fond of my job, I would tell them that if it's that important to them then they should "feel free to give in my name".  Also see https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/23445

Comment: @James really?  what if the charity was the NRA?  would you want someone to make a contribution to the NRA in your name?  ACLU?  Any other organization which is controversial or can become controversial in 10 years?

Comment: @grovkin: Good point.  My employer fortunately makes reasonable choices for their charity drives.